# Google Fonts not working on local device but working on all other devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use Google Fonts on my local laptop but they are not displaying in Google Chrome (working in all other browsers).  I have tested the file on other devices and the file works perfectly on chrome so it must be an issue with my laptop settings/preferences etc.

I have tried the following to resolve this but with no joy:

- Cleared the cache
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome

None of the above has worked and I almost have no more hair to pull out!  If anyone can save me from going bald and can give me the solution that would be awesome!

Comment: are other google fonts working ? Have you tried updating your browser as you said it is working with all other browsers ?

Comment: also did you apply font family in body ?

Comment: Yep had already tried updating and yes font family is in the body. Google just doesn’t want to work :(

Comment: Which OS? Do you see some error in the console? What about serving it from your server and not relying on GG (and not allowing them to track your users btw)? edit: did you try in Private mode/no extension that'd block GG assets?

Comment: Working on Microsoft 10.  No errors in the console log and tested in private mode.  Also really want to avoid hosting the fonts locally as too many problems to look out for with that solution.  Really cannot see why it is not working.  I have tested other google fonts and they seem to be fine - very puzzling!

Comment: I've just tested the file on another laptop and it is working fine!  Now I am at a total loss.  Any suggestions?